# how to create node server that receiving video stream and save the stream as video file?

Tags: node.js, video, video-streaming

I try to look for some examples that doing something like it - but all i found is example of receiving picture and not receiving static stream of video.

I need to receive a video - and save it on the server disk until the client send some flag that the video stream is done.

How to do it ?

Comment: Where's the video coming from?  A web browser?  Is it a pre-recorded file?  Live?  Do you need to process it as it's streaming, or just write it as-is to disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example: you can convert stream to Binary Data and send this: [Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data)

Also you can use MediaStream Recording API, if you want to process video\audio stream: [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API)

Comment: but its a stream of data and maybe this sending as live from webcam - so i cant convert

Comment: You can't stream with XHR.  You also can't use the Fetch API, as none of the browsers have implemented ReadableStream as an HTTP request body yet.  (Coming soon?  Hopefully?)  In the mean time, the only ways to generically stream data from a browser to a server (without knowing its full contents ahead of time) are to use Web Sockets or WebRTC data channel.  If you're streaming media data, you can use WebRTC as-is for this, but it's a real hassle server-side.